# C# Query using Npgsql for Postgresql shows duplicate results and missing table data

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, datasource, npgsql

I am checking out PostgreSQL as potential substitute to SQLServer, I created a test table in a test database in PostgreSQL public schema and added two rows of data to the test table.

Now the problem is when running simple query from C#.net using NpgSQL.dll I get duplicate results, and not all table data is shown.

Here is the code I used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using Npgsql;


namespace PlayingWithPostgres
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // creating the connection string (Server, Port, User id, password, database)
            string conStr = "Server=127.0.0.1; Port=5432; User Id=postgres; Password=Sada1973; Database=CarsTestDB;";
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conStr);
            string comStr = "Select * FROM \"CarsTable\";";
            NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand(comStr, conn);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter ad = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Console.WriteLine("Conection to server established successfuly \n");
            // check if connection is open or not
            if(conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Open");
                conn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            // Fill data table with data and start reading
            ad.Fill(dt);
            NpgsqlDataReader dRead = com.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Contents of table in database: \n");
                while (dRead.Read())
                {
                    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0} \t \n", row[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ne)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Problem connecting to server, Error details {0}", ne.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Closing connections");
                dRead.Close();
                dRead = null;
                conn.Close();
                conn = null;
                com.Dispose();
                com = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of duplicate content is caused by the loop using `While(dRead.Read())` and the loop over the DataRows of the table using the `foreach`. This effectively loops two times on your data.

If you want to use a `DataReader` to loop over the records then you don't need a DataRow and a DataTable, but use the `FieldCount` property of the DataReader and the DataReader indexer for the current record.

```
// Not needed
// ad.Fill(dt);
NpgsqlDataReader dRead = com.ExecuteReader();

while (dRead.Read())
{
   for(int i = 0; i < dRead.FieldCount; i++)
       Console.Write("{0} \t \n", dRead[i].ToString());
}
```

instead if you want to loop over a DataTable and its rows you need to  loop using the `Columns.Count`

```
ad.Fill(dt);
// Not needed
// NpgsqlDataReader dRead = com.ExecuteReader();
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} \t \n", row[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Both ways worked, now I got the whole table data displayed, but still it is duplicated (I mean each record is displayed twice).

Comment: Sorry but can's see your new code. Of course you use just one of the two methods above, right?

Comment: Of course I used only one method but still getting the duplicated results, I am new to PostgreSQL, always worked on SQLServer, that is also why I am using data table and data reader but only running query on one method just for testing PostgreSQL purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the new code to your original question.

Comment: I got it the first method you suggested works fine with duplicates removed, thanks a lot my friend, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your initial approach for every row you are displaying its columns up to column with index = row count. I believe that is not what you wanted to do. You should display every column per row like:

Instead of

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} \t \n", row[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Use:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} \t \n", row.ItemArray[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: No ItemArray could be found for dataTable dt.

Comment: Sorry, meant row. Edited now.